# R - Parse several dates included in a string

Tags: r, date, parsing

I am looking for a way to parse several dates with arbitrary format included in a string.

```
my_date="6 May 2018 10$ party 2018-01-05 meeting"
my_parser(my_date)
# expected : c("2018-05-06 GMT","2018-01-05 GMT")
```

*parsedate* package is able to parse any date format but only if the string contains only one date.

```
library(parsedate)
parse_date("06 may 2018 10$ party",approx=T)
#"2018-05-06 GMT"
parse_date("06 may 2018 10$ party 2018-01-05 meeting",approx=T)
#"2018-01-05 GMT"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can substitute month names to month number, split string by words and the apply parse_date to each splited part:

```
    library(parsedate)
    library(stringr)

    my_date="6 May 2018 10$ party 2018-01-05 meeting"
    month_list <- c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun", "Jul","Aug","Sep", "Oct","Nov","Dec")

    text <-my_date
     for (i in 1:12){
       text <-ifelse(grepl(month_list[i], text), gsub(month_list[i], i, text), text)
      }

    words <- str_split(text, " ")
    words[[1]][grepl("[A-Za-z]", words[[1]])] <-";"
    text <- paste(words[[1]], collapse = " ")
    str<- str_split(text, ";")
    dates<- lapply(str,parse_date)[[1]]
    dates <- dates[!is.na(dates)]
```